# Blank lines in C

Tags: c, coding-style

I'm working through K&R and I notice that their code is extremely tightly spaced.

I haven't developed C since at University, but professionally most source from other languages I've worked in has used blank lines to aid readability.

Is C generally more tightly packed or is it a historical matter related to display size in the 70s?

Exercise 1-16 seems to hinder readability by, for example, an `if` immediately after `for` loop that doesn't have braces.

```
/* mygetline: read a line into s, return length */
int mygetline(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c,i;

  for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
    s[i] = c;
  if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
  }
  s[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples from the K&R that you would space otherwise?

Comment: It's a matter of preference, like in most other languages. FWIW, I'd heard that the reason for tight spacing in K&R was so that it would take up fewer pages when printed. I don't know if that's true...

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle has some comments about code style and historical aspects.

Comment: not historical, I'd only have one extra space, between 'for' & 'if' block. Btw, that doesn't look like K&R style, not the function signature.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. I thought there was a historical element. Although only 30, I did lots of assembler for MicroVax and S/370, so I can relate to the screen size limit on a VT.

Comment: When reading code listings in a book, you also have to consider that they might have a more condensed format than normal to keep the page-count of the book within the limits set by the publisher.

Comment: Yet another example why K&R is not suitable for learning C programming. It is not only outdated about the C language, it is outdated in every way. Standard compliance, coding practice, coding style...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Every line of code you keep on the screen is saved time when programming.**

In the days of the K&R being written, the screens were 80 characters wide by 24 lines tall.  This is all that you could see at the time on one page.  Visual editors were not yet written - you had tools that were more along the lines of [ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)) (written in 1971, [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming) is from 1972).

When working in such an environment, vertical space is important.  Unnecessary braces to denote a block represent a 'wasted' line on the screen.  Putting an open curly brace on its own line is another wasted line.  Elses with ears `} else {`  represents two lines saved on the screen.

When tracing program flow it can become difficult to keep things in your head, your code size becomes limited to about one screen size (even today that is true), maybe two.  While printing lines in line editors isn't *cumbersome* it isn't just scrolling down the mouse on the side of the screen (or hitting page down in vi), it is commands such as `.,.+10p` to print the next ten lines, or `.-10,.+10` to "scroll up 10 lines and display the next ten lines too" - it isn't exactly *easy* either to navigate the code, or move from "page" to "page".

If one looks at [How many lines of code is too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981/how-many-lines-of-code-is-too-many) on StackOverflow, one will see several references to "screen size".

We unconsciously can keep in our head what we can see - swapping out to screen.  If you were to be asked a question about something that is on the page of a book you are reading, it is in short term memory and you can quickly see it and look at it to get the rest of the memory quickly.  When asked about something two pages ago, you may have to go back and refresh your memory.  This is even more critical when working with programs because the small things matter (`x++ vs ++x`).  So now you've got to go back and "scroll" with ed, which takes some thought too (which becomes one of the spots of [seven plus or minus two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two) and pushed out something else).

---

**On the other "not space saving" things in the block of code and their reasons...**

If anything, I am surprised at the code at not saving *more* space:

```
int mygetline(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c,i;

  for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
    s[i] = c;
  if (c == '\n')
    s[i++] = c;
  s[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

By moving the increment into the assignment of the array two lines can be removed (and yes, there are even more lines that can be removed for more dense code, the K&R appears to maintain the code style of the open brace for a function on a line by itself and a blank line between declarations and code).

The open brace on a line by itself is likely from the original style of C functions declaration.  From Section 1.7 in K&R (second edition):

```
/* power:  raise base to n-th power; n >= 0 */
/*         (old-style version) */
power(base, n)
int base, n;
{
    int i, p;

    p = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        p = p * base;
    return p;
}
```

You can see the awkwardness of moving the open curly for `power` onto a previous line - and if anything, it helps keep the function declaration identifiable.

Likewise, keeping a declaration block at the top and then a blank line.  This was important in some early compliers where declarations could only happen at the top of a block.  Separating the two helped ensure you didn't make a mistake by interweaving declarations and code (this was prohibited as recently as C89 - [C89, Mixing Variable Declarations and Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488503/c89-mixing-variable-declarations-and-code)).  Making the declaration block separate could save you a pass through the complier (not necessarily a quick thing).

Comment: Would you be good enough to demonstrate how you would refactor that code?

Comment: @retrodev what refactoring would you like to see?

Comment: You mention moving the increment into the assignment. If you were writing that function, how would you go about it?

Comment: @retrodev I already did it - `{ s[i] = c; ++i; }` becomes `s[i++] = c;`

Answer (score 2):

K&R was written in the heart of the "Glass TTY" era, when the standard resolution screen was 80 characters by 24 lines.   Whitespace was a luxury that usually lost out to the desire to keep the relevant lines of code visible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a historical dimension to your question. Computers were not always having a screen attached to them. Just think of old command line/ DOS boxes having limited number of lines per screen. Then you can imagine that a programmer wanted to see as much code as possible at once.

Furthermore with teletypewriters, etc. you could not even be sure to have a screen. Blank lines were a waste.

Comment: I remember a time where every blank character in `BASIC` was a wasted byte, especially when your total memory was only 32 or 64 kB (not MB or GB as nowadays). Otoh, there are still some dinos that want to limit the line length to 80 or even less. All of them missed the bus.

Comment: Whoooh... 32kb!!! Luxury - I remember programming Basic with 1kB, What I would have been able to do with 32....